# Keyerror while trying to replace null values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, keyerror

I'm getting this new type (new for me) of key error when I try to replace null values in a column.

```
df['GarageYrBlt'] = df['GarageYrBlt'].map(lambda x: df.loc[x, 'YearBuilt'] if df.loc[x, 'GarageYrBlt'].isnull() else df.loc[x, 'GarageYrBlt'])
```

I'm trying to use a lambda function to map null values to values in another column, otherwise telling the function to let that value be.

I'm getting this key error.

```
KeyError: 2003.0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
KeyError: 2003
```

I then tried changing the lambda function to this

```
df['GarageYrBlt'].map(lambda x: replace(df.loc[x, 'YearBuilt'], NaN) if df.loc[x, 'GarageYrBlt'].isnull() else df.loc[x, 'GarageYrBlt'])
```

Nothing changed from the previous status. Please pinpoint what I'm doing wrong and how I could do things better. Thanks.

Comment: 2003.0 and 2003 are not in the index

Comment: It's not. Both of those are values in the first row of the dataset.

Comment: ....that's why you are getting a key error

Comment: How do I resolve this then? @It_is_Chris

Comment: Do not use map or lambda use np.where

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm. I'd still love to know why lambda and map didn't work. Please do tell me as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.  @It_is_Chris